# PHP mail() function to all users from clients.json file

Tags: php, json, email, submit

I'm trying to send email to all the users that I have in my JSON file. 
My question is, how to make this work so when I click on send, this will happen?THANKS!!! Code:

```
<?php 
  $sData = file_get_contents('data/clients.json');
  $jData = json_decode($sData);
  if ($jData == null) {
    echo 'System update';
  }

  $sEmailsOfAllUsers = $jData->data->$sUserName->email;
  $sMessage = $_POST['txtEmailToAllUsers'];

  foreach ($jData->data as $sUserName) {
      $from = "PETRABANK";
      $to = $sEmailsOfAllUsers;
      $subject = "Email to all users";
      $headers = "From:" . $from;
      mail($to, $subject, $sMessage, $headers);
      echo "The email message was sent to all users.";
  }
?>
```

JSON file data/clients.json

```
{
    "data": {
        "username": {
            "email": "petrajakubcova@hotmail.com",
        }
    }
}
```

the HTML form

```
<h3>Send email to all users</h3>
  <form id="sEmailToAllUsers" action="????" method="POST">
    <input name="txtEmailToAllUsers" id="txtEmailToAllUsers" type="text">
    <button>SEND</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like when it has multiple e-mail addresses?

Comment: At a first glance the code seems legit (minus the echo which should be outside the foreach loop and json file), what issues are you having? Have you configured mailserver from the config?

Comment: `{
    "data": {
        "username1": {
            "email": "p@p.com",
            "lastName": "jjjj"
        }
        "username1": {
            "email": "l@l.com",
            "lastname": "v@v.com
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @ka_lin I dont know how to make it work, so after I click on SEND this action would happen. :/ THANKS!

Comment: @JonStirling I added it :-)

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? If you have already parsed that JSON to an array, what keeps you from using that data?

Comment: @NicoHaase I dont know what action should the form have and how to make it work, so after I click on the button SEND it will actually happen.

Comment: Why not use the script that actually sends the mail?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use email in foreach loop it self to send mail to all customer in one shot or you have to fetch all email in different loop and and merge them by comma ","

```
<?php 
  $sData = file_get_contents('data/clients.json');
  $jData = json_decode($sData);
  if ($jData == null) {
    echo 'System update';
  }

  $sMessage = $_POST['txtEmailToAllUsers'];

  foreach ($jData->data as $sUserName) {
      $from = "PETRABANK";
      $to = $sUserName->username->email;
      $subject = "Email to all users";
      $headers = "From:" . $from;
      mail($to, $subject, $sMessage, $headers);
      echo "The email message was sent to all users.";
  }
?>
```

This code will help you in sending mail to all customer one by one.

Comment: @PetraJakub I'm glad to help. Remember it is custom on Stack Overflow to upvote answers that help, and to use the green checkmark to identify the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Under "action" in the form you are supposed to reference the file that will process the data, so in this case I'm guessing you should just reference the file that you are in:

```
<form id="sEmailToAllUsers" action="/yourfile.php" method="POST">
```

Make sure you don't put the json file. I'm quite new myself :D But I hope this helps!